# Crawling google search results with PHP Curl , was working but seems to have stopped

Tags: php, curl, google-search

Hi Im attempting to crawl google search results, just for my own learning, but also to see can I speed up getting access to direct URLS (Im aware of their API but I just thought Id try this for now).

It was working fine but it seems to have stopped, its simply returning nothing now, Im unsure if its something I did, but I can say that I had this in a for loop to allow the `start` parameter to increase and Im wondering may that have caused problems.

Is it possible Google can block an IP from crawling?

Thanks..

```
$url = "https://www.google.ie/search?q=adrian+de+cleir&start=1&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=D730U7KgGfDT7AbNpoBY#channel=fflb&q=adrian+de+cleir&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

# Create a DOM parser object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

# Parse the HTML from Google.
# The @ before the method call suppresses any warnings that
# loadHTML might throw because of invalid HTML in the page.
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

# Iterate over all the <a> tags
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('h3') as $link) {

        $actual_link = $link->getElementsbyTagName('a');
        foreach ($actual_link as $single_link) {
        # Show the <a href>
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($single_link->getAttribute('href'));
        echo '</pre>';      


}
}
```

Comment: yes of course their able and allowed to block your ip if you requested too often. did you tried to run your script on another machine?

Comment: Not yet, But I will go home and try it, I also tried including a proxy with 'curl' but no luck

Comment: just to expand on the above, I changed `h3` to `div` just as a test and it showed me some data (however nothing in the search results obviously

Comment: just print out the whole html and paste here

Comment: Ok, it turns out its loading different html than it was before, saying "302 Moved
The document has moved here." The 'here' takes me to another link for search. Perhaps this is a preventative measure by google

Comment: yes its a redirect that ever browser is able to understand but curls like your script are too trivial and thats how google prevents curl bots apperently

Answer (score 1):

Given below is the program I have written in python. But it is not completed fully. Right now it only gets the first page and prints all the href links found on the result.

We can use sets and remove the redundant links from the result set.

```
import requests<br>
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def search_spider(max_pages, search_string):    
    page = 0   
    search_string = search_string.replace(' ','+')   
    while page <= max_pages:  
    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?num=10000&q=' + search_string + '#q=' + search_string + '&start=' + str(page)   
    print("URL to search - " + url)   
    source_code = requests.get(url)   
    count = 1   
    plain_text = source_code.text   
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)   
    for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class" : ""}):   
        href = link.get('href')   
        input_string = slice_string(href)   
        print(input_string)   
        count += 1   
    page += 10    


def slice_string(input_string):   
    input_string = input_string.lstrip("/url?q=")   
    index_c = input_string.find('&')   
    input_string = input_string[:index_c]   
    return input_string   

search_spider(1,"bangalore cabs")
```

This program will search for bangalore cabs in google.

Thanks,
Karan

Answer (score 0):

You can check if Google blocked you by the following simple curl script command:

```
curl -sSLA Mozilla "http://www.google.com/search?q=linux" | html2text -width 80
```

You may install `html2text` in order to convert html into plain text.

Normally you should use [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) provided by Google to avoid any limitations, so you could retrieve search results in easier way by having access to different formats (such as XML or JSON).